# Is there a CuPy version supporting (axis) option in cupy.unique() function? Any workaround?

Tags: python, gpu, unique, axis, cupy

I'm looking for a GPU CuPy counterpart of numpy.unique() with axis option supported.

I have a Cupy 2D array that I need to remove its duplicated rows. Unfortunately, cupy.unique() function flattens the array and returns 1D array with unique values. I'm looking for a function like numpy.unique(arr, axis=0) to solve this but CuPy does not support the (axis) option yet

```py
x = cp.array([[1,2,3,4], [4,5,6,7], [1,2,3,4], [10,11,12,13]])
y = cp.unique(x)
y_r = np.unique(cp.asnumpy(x), axis=0)

print('The 2D array:\n', x)
print('Required:\n', y_r, 'But using CuPy')
print('The flattened unique array:\n', y)

print('Error producing line:', cp.unique(x, axis=0))

I expect a 2D array with unique rows but I get a 1D array with unique numbers instead. Any ideas about how to implement this with CuPy or numba?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of CuPy version `8.0.0b2`, the function `cupy.lexsort` is correctly implemented. This function can be used as a workaround (albeit probably not the most efficient) for `cupy.unique` with the axis argument.

Assuming the array is 2D, and that you want to find the unique elements along axis 0 (else transpose/swap as appropriate):

```
    ###################################
    # replacement for numpy.unique with option axis=0
    ###################################

    def cupy_unique_axis0(array):
        if len(array.shape) != 2:
            raise ValueError("Input array must be 2D.")
        sortarr     = array[cupy.lexsort(array.T[::-1])]
        mask        = cupy.empty(array.shape[0], dtype=cupy.bool_)
        mask[0]     = True
        mask[1:]    = cupy.any(sortarr[1:] != sortarr[:-1], axis=1)
        return sortarr[mask]
```

Check [the original `cupy.unique` source code](https://github.com/cupy/cupy/blob/v7.5.0/cupy/manipulation/add_remove.py#L19) (which this is based on) if you want to implement the return_stuff arguments, too. I don't need those myself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I'm not looking for unique (elements) along a particular axis, I'm looking for unique rows or columns for example:

if x = [[ 0  1  2  3  4]
          [ 0  1  2  3  4]
          [10 11 12 13 14]
          [15 16 17 18 19]
          [20 21 22 23 24]]

Them it must return:

[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24]]

Comment: That's what this function does, the way I phrased it may have been confusing. You can test it with your arrays: ```x  = cupy.arange(25).reshape((5,5)); x[1]    = x[0]; print(x); print(cupy_unique_axis0(x))```.

Comment: This is really helpful. I really appreciate it. Thanks!